# Groovy Eclipse XML RPC - error detecting run time property

Tags: eclipse, groovy

As per [this example](http://groovy.codehaus.org/XMLRPC) provided in the groovy site, I have tried to implement an exactly same XML RPC Server on my eclipse.

```
import groovy.net.xmlrpc.*
import java.net.ServerSocket

def server = new XMLRPCServer()
server.echo = {return it}
def serverSocket = new ServerSocket( 9004 )
server.startServer(serverSocket)
```

The above code will launch a server on 9004 only when I run from groovy console. When I run the same from Eclipse it fails to run and shows the following exception

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: echo for class: groovy.net.xmlrpc.XMLRPCServer
    at GServer.run(GServer.groovy:7)
```

Perhaps it is unable to understand the dynamic addition of the new property called `echo` but I am not sure. How can I fix this?

PS : I am running 
Eclipse Galileo 3.5

Groovy eclipse plugin installed

Groovy xml rpc jar is on the classpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some bugs with the launcher in the Groovy-Eclipse that ran on Eclipse 3.5.  I'd recommend that you upgrade to Groovy-Eclipse 2.6.0 on Eclipse 3.7.  I'd bet that your problem would go away.